# Customize Android permission request message?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

Following the Embarcadero [Android Permission Model documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Android_Permission_Model) and looking at the Camera cpp mobile snippet sample i can now succesfully request user permissions.

But, i can't figure out how to customize the request message.  I'm only asking for permission to `read external storage` - i don't want the message asking about photos etc.

[image]

How can i customize this message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prompt message is controlled by the OS, not the app. The message text is generic to each permission being asked for. You can't customize the text.

The best you can do is display a rationale message to the user before asking for permission, or after the permission has been denied ([`TPermissionsService.RequestPermissions()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Permissions.TPermissionsService.RequestPermissions) has an optional `AOnDisplayRationale` callback for that purpose), then you can explain to the user why the permission is needed.  See [App permissions best practices](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes.html) in Android's developer documentation for more details, especially the section about [Explain why you need permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes.html#be_transparent).

This is a limitation of Android itself, not of Embarcadero.